# How to convert a RestTemplate to String when communicate between micro services in Java

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, microservices

I'm trying to communicate between two micro services here. I want to read the message written in one micro service from another micro service. I have used a RestTemplate for that. But When I tried to convert it to a String it won't coming. I'm getting this
'The method exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class, Object...) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, null, Class)'

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String test(){
String a = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/KDSystem/Testpro/pros", HttpMethod.GET,null,String.class).getBody().toString();
return a;
    }
```

Any idea of how to do that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `getForObject(URI url, Class<T> responseType)` method:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String test(){
  return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/KDSystem/Testpro/pros", String.class);
}
```

About the method `exchange(String, HttpMethod, HttpEntity<?>, Class, Object...)`  according to exception text: you are trying to pass '(String, String, null, Class)' but the second argument should be HttpMethod.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to show this using @GET rather than @RequestMapping? When I tried to write the same code using at GET it won't work now

Comment: You mean @GetMapping ?

Comment: I want to display the data like in a @GET method